# Imbalance corpus using label propagation for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to do user location classification with **semi-supervised** learning.

The dataset is used to do user location classification in tweet, the mixture of all messages posted by a user is considered as one sample of this user.

The number of samples vary 8 categories (locations) is `24`, `233`, `780`, `804`, `144`, `91`, `503`, `243` as shown in **confusion matrix**.

I want to **predict** the user's location via these messages.

I assume that some labeled data are unlabeled, which labels are set as `-1`. Using Label propagation in `scikit-learning` leads to that all unlabeled data are predicted as the label `3` that the amount of the samples is the most.

**Question:** Which method should I use to handle this imbalance semi-supervised texts classification?

Here is the full snippet of my code:

```
from document import readfile
trainDocs,trainLabels,nu1 = readfile(r'train', 700)
valDocs,valLabels,nu2 = readfile(r'valid', 100)
testDocs,testLabels,nu3 = readfile(r'test', 200)
#Valids,nu4,userIds = readfile(r'classifiedValid',1200)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
#count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words="english",decode_error='ignore')
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(valDocs+trainDocs+testDocs)
#print (X_train_counts.shape)
#print (X_train_counts)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

#tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf = False).fit(X_train_counts)
#X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
#print (X_train_tf.shape)
#print (X_train_tf)
#
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf = X_train_tfidf.toarray()
#X_train_tfidf.shape

print (X_train_tfidf.shape)
#print (X_train_tfidf)

#X_test_counts = count_vect.transform(Valids)
#X_test_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_test_counts)
#X_test_tfidf = X_test_tfidf.toarray()

#from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.semi_supervised import label_propagation

labels = np.array(valLabels+trainLabels+testLabels)
unlabeled_set = np.arange(len(trainLabels+testLabels))
#testLabels2[unlabeled_set] = -1
unlabeled_set2 = np.arange(len(trainLabels+testLabels))
unlabeled_set2[unlabeled_set] += len(valLabels)
labels[unlabeled_set2] = -1

print 'start'
#clf = SVC(C=1.0, gamma=0.10000000000000001).fit(X_train_tfidf,np.array(trainLabels+valLabels))
clf = label_propagation.LabelSpreading(gamma = 0.25, max_iter=100).fit(X_train_tfidf,labels)
predicted_labels = clf.transduction_[unlabeled_set2]
print (np.mean(predicted_labels == np.array(trainLabels+testLabels)))
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.classification_report(np.array(trainLabels+testLabels),predicted_labels))

cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(np.array(trainLabels+testLabels), predicted_labels,
                          labels=clf.classes_)
print("Confusion matrix")
print(cm)

precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.00      0.00      0.00        24
      1       0.00      0.00      0.00       233
      2       0.00      0.00      0.00       780
      3       0.28      1.00      0.44       804
      4       0.00      0.00      0.00       144
      5       0.00      0.00      0.00        91
      6       0.00      0.00      0.00       503
      7       0.00      0.00      0.00       243
avg / total 0.08 0.28 0.13 2822

Confusion matrix
[[  0   0   0  24   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 233   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 780   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 804   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 144   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0  91   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 503   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 243   0   0   0   0]]
```